Multi-Drop Bus using Java Android
let's see if anyone can help me with this...
I have a Java application on Android that is on a Cashless device. I have this one connected to a Bianchi brand coffee machine, with the MDB cable. It turns out that in my Java code, I can read the codes (10H, 11H, 12H, 17H...) that the VMC sends me. But I can't read the SUB-CODES because I don't know how to do it. I'm attaching a screenshot of what codes and subcodes I'm referring to from the MDB 4.3 documentation.
mdb_documentation_4.3
My Java code to listen to the VMC messages, is this:
private void startListeningToVMC() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            short[] buffer = new short[MDB_BUFFER];
            int count = MDB_COUNT;
            int timeout = MDB_TIMEOUT;
            int interval = MDB_INTERVAL;
            int returnOnModeset = MDB_RETURN_ON_MODE_SET;
            while (true) {
                int bytesRead = mdbManager.mdbRead(slaveFd, buffer, count, timeout, interval, returnOnModeset);
                if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                    processReceivedData(buffer, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }).start();
   } 

I appreciate very much any help. Thanks!! :D
I want to get more data from the VMC.
